# Angular 2 set default content in the router-outlet

Tags: angular

I want to set some default text inside the router-outlet until it is populated.

I have a parent component that will display the child route component within the router-outlet on that page.

There are 2 buttons that will populate the router-outlet with the child component when clicked. How can i place content inside the router outlet eg. 'Click an options to display the data' then once the button is clicked this message clears and the child component displays in the router outlet?

```
<div class="container pt-3">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="btn btn-outline-success float-left"
            routerLink="/unpaid/people">
            View People
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-outline-success float-right"
            routerLink="/unpaid/bills">
            View Bills
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<router-outlet>Click an options to display the data</router-outlet>
```

EDIT
here are my routes

```
path: 'unpaid', component: UnpaidBillsComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'people', component: UnpaidPeopleComponent},
      {path: 'bills', component: UnpaidBillListComponent}
    ]
```

Comment: you cannot do this , you need to look at router events in order to show a loading or any text you want to appear

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> default text inside the router-outlet until it is populated

Firstly, your assumption here is wrong, content is not inserted *inside* the outlet, but *below* it.

---

You cannot set a default content in the template, but you can set the default route which contains your default content. Simply use `path: ''` and use a `component` with your "default" template.

---

Create a component with the "default" template you need:

```
@Component({template: `Default template here`})
export class DefaultTemplateComponent {}
```

And add it to your routes.

```
children: [
  {path: '', component: DefaultTemplateComponent},
  {path: 'people', component: UnpaidPeopleComponent},
  {path: 'bills', component: UnpaidBillListComponent},
]
```

Comment: So are you saying create a third component that displays the message?

Comment: Yep, this does the trick. Thought there might be an easier way or less work than having to create a new component for a simple line of text but it works anyway, so thanks.

Comment: It's not that much, really. The snippet I posted is minimal but it's exactly what you need: It's only two lines over what you had before: exporting a class and adding an empty path to route definition. You don't need selector or styles in your component, so you can really just inline it with `template:`.

Answer (score 10):

In Template:

```
<p *ngIf="showDefaultMessage">Click an options to display the data</p>
<router-outlet (activate)="toggleDefaultMessage(false)" (deactivate)="toggleDefaultMessage(true)"></router-outlet>
```

then in Component just toggle "showDefaultMessage" property:

```
private showDefaultMessage = true; // default state

toggleDefaultMessage(state: boolean) {
    this.showDefaultMessage = state;
}
```

Comment: Call me old school, but I prefer this implementation. Although I wouldn't declare a callback method at all; you can just unset `showDefaultMessage` in the template directly: `<router-outlet (activate)="showDefaultMessage=false">`

Answer (score 1):

```
children: [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/people', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'people', component: UnpaidPeopleComponent},
  {path: 'bills', component: UnpaidBillListComponent}
]
```

Comment: I'm not wanting to redirect to there, i'm wanting to display content in the router-outlet before one of the child routes is accessed.

Comment: then you have to create another component for this text "Click an options to display the data" and redirect to the same component.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" 
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
  <h5 *ngIf="rla.isActive" class="beauty">Click on any button to start!</h5>
</a>
</div>
```

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Answer (score 0):

create component you want to see on parent component load and add to children

```
path: 'unpaid', component: UnpaidBillsComponent,
children: [
  {path: 'people', component: UnpaidPeopleComponent},
  {path: 'bills', component: UnpaidBillListComponent},
  {path: 'default', component: DefaultComponent}
]
```

and when you open parent component open directly full path with default

```
router.navigate(['unpaid/default'])
```