# How to set a child component as a default route for a router-outlet?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I am using `Lazyloading` and I have two `router-outlets`. the problem occurs when I want to navigate to another child route. I get this error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
>       at defaultUrlMatcher (router.js:566)
>       at match (router.js:2221) .....

My main app-router module looks like,

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'web/welcome' , pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'web', redirectTo: 'web/welcome' , pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'web',
        loadChildren: 'app/core/website/modules/website.module#WebSiteModule',
        data: { preload: true }
     },
    {
        path: 'dbapp', canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        loadChildren: 'app/core/database/modules/db.module#DbModule',
        data: { preload: true }
     },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404',  pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, data: { message: 'We Could Not Serve Your Request!'}},
];
```

and for `dbapp` I have this routing module,

```
const dbRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DbHomeComponent,
    data: { preload: true },
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: UserDashboardComponent },
      {
        path: 'registry',
        canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
        data: { expectedRole: { roles: ['reg'] } },
        loadChildren:
          'app/core/database/database-cores/registry-core/modules/registry.module#RegistryModule'
        // canActivateChild: [RoleGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: 'embryology',
        canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
        data: { expectedRole: { roles: ['emb'] } },
        loadChildren:
          'app/core/database/database-cores/embryology-core/modules/embryology-routing.module#EmbryologyRoutingModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'nursing',
        canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
        data: { expectedRole: { roles: ['nur'] } },
        loadChildren:
          'app/core/database/database-cores/embryology-core/modules/embryology-routing.module#EmbryologyRoutingModule'
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

My map looks like the following,

[image]
Router Map, Underlined `components` are `router-outlets`

so according to my config. the routing starts at `https://www.artngcore.com:4200/web/welcome` and after authentication the route changes to `https://www.artngcore.com:4200/dbapp`

I managed to navigate to `UserDashboardComponent` as a default route, my problem if I do routing to the other children, i.e. `routerLink="/dbapp/registry"`

How can I show a child component as a default route and navigate to other children routes?

Comment: Did you use something to auto generate that router graphic or did you manually create it?

Comment: @Zze I am using [Augury](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd?hl=en)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved, the answer is derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46861017/2157801),

so my `dbapp` routing module should be like this,

```
const dbRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DbHomeComponent,
    data: { preload: true },
    children: [
      { path: '', component: UserDashboardComponent },
      {
        path: 'registry',
        canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
        data: { expectedRole: { roles: ['reg'] } },
        loadChildren:
          'app/core/database/database-cores/registry-core/modules/registry.module#RegistryModule'
        // canActivateChild: [RoleGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: 'embryology',
        canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
        data: { expectedRole: { roles: ['emb'] } },
        loadChildren:
          'app/core/database/database-cores/embryology-core/modules/embryology-routing.module#EmbryologyRoutingModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'nursing',
        canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
        data: { expectedRole: { roles: ['nur'] } },
        loadChildren:
          'app/core/database/database-cores/embryology-core/modules/embryology-routing.module#EmbryologyRoutingModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

all what I had to do is to change the routing matching strategy,     `pathMatch: 'full'` should not be included